# MVVM Light - Changing the startup URI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Having created a new WPF 4.5 MVVM Light Application, I wanted to change the startup URI so that I could do some checks before the app starts.  I made the following change to App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="MvvmLight1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MvvmLight1.ViewModel"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
```

To:

```
<Application x:Class="MvvmLight1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MvvmLight1.ViewModel"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
```

And added an `OnStartup` method to the `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    static App()
    {
        DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnStartup(e);

        MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
        win.Show();
    }
}
```

Doing this seems to change the context that the window runs in.  I did try setting the data context to the MainViewModel, but this didn't seem to help.

Comment: What change did you make to your `Application` definition? I can't see any difference... you still have `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`. And where are you setting the `DataContext`? I don't see that either.

Comment: Well spotted, although that was entirely down to my poor formatting!

Comment: As far as the DataContext goes, changing it made no difference, which is why I didn't include it.

Comment: Changing it from what to what? Please show us so that we can have some context of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to have added the `Startup` handler to your `Application` definition... try this:

```
<Application x:Class="MvvmLight1.App"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MvvmLight1.ViewModel"
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
     mc:Ignorable="d" Startup="OnStartup">   <!--   <<< Here   -->
```

UPDATE >>>

You can't use any method for this... you don't seem to be using the right method definition for your start up handler... mine looks like this:

```
public void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Try adding the `object sender` parameter to your handler.

Comment: Okay, that doesn't work.  However, if I set the startup to a new method it does work.  However, a breakpoint on the new startup method reveals that it never actually fires it!  Why does this work?  (BTW a breakpoint on the `override OnStartup` reveals that it executes that whether or not the startup property is set.

Comment: I'm overriding the `OnStartup` method - that's not just a random method.  Like I said, I've tried adding the handler, but it never fires (even though it does seem to fix the issue)

Comment: My mistake. Instead of overriding the `OnStartup` method, try handling the [`Application.Startup Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx) with the required [System.Windows.StartupEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.startupeventhandler.aspx) like I have shown. Then the handler will get called.

Answer (score 0):

You should have something in App.xaml.cs like:

```
base.OnStartup(e);
var window = new MainWindowView();
var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
window.DataContext = viewModel;
window.Show();
```

or in MainView.xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <vms:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

UPDATE >>>

Okej I downloaded MVVM Light Project 4.5 WPF add to my VS2012 and what i did:
1. Deleted StartUp in App.xaml
2. Deleted data context decralation in MainWindow.xaml
3. Create code like:

```
  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnStartup(e);
     var window = new MainWindow {DataContext = new MainViewModel(new DataService())};
     window.Show();
  }
```

And everything works fine.

Comment: This doesn't work because the main view model in MVVM light has a constructor that takes a data service.  Additionally, it doesn't explain why it works ehere the startuuri is set the the mainview

Comment: Okej edited my post. I download WPF 4.5 MVVM Light Application and did something like in my post.

Comment: You're right... it's the DataContext declaration... once it's deleted it works without explicitly handling the startup event (which I still don't understand).
  
However, this now means that the design time data cannot be seen.